# Print array list in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips

So I need help printing off an array list in MIPS. The following code is the array that's provided. How do I print that off to say "Original array is: " Here is the code that I have so far

```
.data
list:     .word     1 2 3 4 5 6

.text
.globl  main
main:
    li      $v0,4                   # print syscall
    la      $a0,list
    syscall

    li      $v0,8                   # read array
    la      $a0,list
    li      $a1,1000
    syscall

    la      $a0,list
    jal     list.length                  # get array length

    move    $a1,$v0                 # save array length
    la      $a0,list
    jal     reverse

    li      $v0,4                   # print array
    la      $a0,list
    syscall

    li      $v0,10                  # exit
    syscall
```

Comment: If the problem is just to print an array, why do you read (syscall 8)? What means `jal list.length`? What is the `reverse` procedure that you call? Why do you call print_string (syscall 4) to print ints? When do you loop over values of your array? Come on, you can do much better.  We can help, but you must give us some decent code before.

Comment: So my code is to reverse the array recursively. My code is working and I got it to print with the string but now I need it to print in reverse. And I’m having a problem printing it backwards

Comment: I am certain that your code is not working. You call two inexistent procedures. To print the array, you need its length. Add a var with it (6) and store it in a reg(say $s0). Store @list in another reg (say $s1) . Then you just have to do `print: lw $a0, 0($s1); li $v0, 1; syscall; addi $s0, $s0, -1; addi $s1, $s1, 4; bne $s0,$0, print`